# What determines who shows up in my Castle?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

When I'm in my castle a couple heroes are in there I can chat with and receive gifts from. Is it just random who appears here? I'd like to have only heroes That I am a fan of, or are part of my team appear, but that does not seem the case most of the time.

Setting them as favorite seems to have no effect.

My top commander seems to be set by the first slot of team 1, but even then I'm not sure.

Comment: adding this as a comment because it's an experience based answer: no it changes from time to time, but I mostly see my most used heroes. But because I only use 6 certain builds from time to time there are some stragglers who will appear every time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edited as the most recent update made it no longer all random:*

**Using the following Diagram:**
[image: this image was taken from a quick google search, I added the numbers]

**Unit 1** is set by placing a hero in the ***first*** slot of your ***first*** party.
(You can tell which party is your first by looking at the white circles under the party switcher)
This is the unit everyone in PvP and your friends will see when they challenge or greet you.

**Units 2, 3, 4, and 5** are the members of your currently selected party.
IF YOUR FIRST PARTY IS SELECTED, Units 2, 3, and 4 will be the other members of that party, as Unit 1 is already in the party, and Unit 5 will be random.

**Units 6, 7, and 8** are all random units, see below.

**Unit 9** is one of your friends, your friends will appear at the bottom.

I've confirmed this by going to the Home screen, then the Battle screen over and over again, each time the bottom characters changed.

For the random slots, there were no patterns, not in the colour of units that appear (there were times where most of them were red, and times with no reds at all), not in weapon, level, star rating, or who is on your other teams.

You can even get two of the same hero, I have a 4-star and 3-star Olivia, and both just showed up at the same time.